# PHP Headers Parsing

Tags: php, http-headers

I am having a problem parsing http headers with PHP.

When I run this code:

```
$headers = getallheaders();
```

all headers are loaded into the `$headers` array.  However, if any array key name has a "-" in it, then the corresponding result is null.  For example:

```
echo $headers[User-Agent];
```

will return null, whereas:

```
echo $headers[Host];
```

will return the value normally.

Is this a bug or I am missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Just try using doube/single quotes like the below code:

```
<?php
  $headers = getallheaders();
  echo $headers["User-Agent"];
  echo $headers["Host"];
?>
```

Output:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/44.0.2403.89 Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36main.xfiddle.com
```

Try this code in [php fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/)

Comment: still not working in my environment while it is working in the fiddle site, Do you have a clue?

Answer (score 1):

Try dumping `$headers` and see what is in it.

```
var_dump($headers);
```

Find available keys, and use them.

```
var_dump($headers['User-Agent']);
```

Note that keys are case sensitive.